# In the SQL Server RESTORE statement, in what time zone is the STOPAT argument?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, restore

SQL Server can perform point-in-time restores using the [STOPAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) argument. In what time zone is that date and time value?

- Is it UTC?
- Is it local for the server the backup was taken?
- Is it local for the server the backup is restored?

Comment: It's local to the server, based on the transaction log, so your second option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer: From when the backup was taken**

I actually wasn't sure of the answer, so I just made a database, put it in full recovery model, took a full backup, did some work (create a couple tables named after the time I created them) and then started restores. Restored the full and then attempted to apply the log backups.

When I did that I had to specify the time zone from when the changes were made - from when the backup was taken. If I tried to use the new time zone's setting, it errored - bad timing.

So the answer to your question in my experience with SQL Server 2012 and 2008R2 - appears to be "The local time from when the backup was taken"

This backs up my expectation before testing. The way the log records are written and the way the backups are taken - that makes sense.

That said - I can't imagine a ton of situations where the time zone is changing with the need to worry about point in time recovery?

Comment: Thanks for providing a verified answer! (I think not using UTC is a small design flaw in SQL Server because it is more error prone. But that's off-topic here.)

Comment: You raise a valid point it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Mike that its a good question and +1 for that.

Mike has answered your question. Out of curiosity, I tried to confirmed that using an undocumented (but widely used) function `fn_dump_dblog`.

This will have a `Begin Time` and `End Time` and you can use that from the T-Log backup to determine at what point-in-time you want to recover.

The `Begin Time` and `End Time` are both **from the server that the backup was taken**.

I have servers in NY, HK and LD and tried on them and it confirms it.

Below is a screenshot that explains it :

[image]

Thanks for posting a good question.